# error Using bcc with play mailer and scala: addBcc is not a member of play.api.libs.mailer.Email

Tags: scala, email, playframework, mailer

I'm using play mailer (https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) to send emails from my application to a group of person but I don't want that a recipient can see the addresses of the other recipients (in the TO field) I found that bcc can resolve this, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
package controllers

import play.api.libs.mailer._
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.json._

class MailerApi @Inject() (mailerClient: MailerClient) extends Controller {
  def sendEmail = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val subject: String = (request.body \ "subject").as[String]

    val cid = "1234"
    val email = Email(
      subject,
      "Me <email1@gmail.com>",
      Seq("Miss TO email2@gmail.com"),
      // adds attachment
      attachments = Seq(),
      // sends text, HTML or both...
      bodyText = Some("A text message"),
      bodyHtml = Some("content")).addBcc("<email1@gmail.com>")
    mailerClient.send(email)
    Future.successful(Ok("ok !!"))
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
value addBcc is not a member of play.api.libs.mailer.Email
Read from stdout: possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value addBcc'?
```

Comment: `addBcc` is not defined on `Email` case class. if you look at the code of `Email` definition https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala#L284 here you will i takes `Seq[String]` as bcc parameters. So, you need to provide it instantiating `Email` itself.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I tried this http://pastebin.com/WhWvE3JF but stay have the same list of recipients in the TO field

Comment: I haven't tested this, and I think to field will have only 1 email which you provided others will be in bcc field and recipient can not see them in email.

and I did not even understand what do you mean by it "stay have the same list of recipients in the TO field"

Comment: I mean that the recipient can see the addresses of the other recipients (in the TO field)

Comment: if that's the case then you can raise a issue for it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

package controllers

```
import play.api.libs.mailer._
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.json._

class MailerApi @Inject() (mailerClient: MailerClient) extends Controller {
  def sendEmail = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val subject: String = (request.body \ "subject").as[String]

    val cid = "1234"
    val email = Email(
      subject,
      "ExcelWay <email1@gmail.com>",
      Seq("Miss TO email2@gmail.com"),
      // adds attachment
      attachments = Seq(),
      // sends text, HTML or both...
      bodyText = Some("A text message"),
      bodyHtml = Some("content"),
      bcc= Seq("bccemail@example.com")
      )
    mailerClient.send(email)
    Future.successful(Ok("ok !!"))
  }
}
```

Comment: edited my answer it will work now and I did not exactly run the code but its just a syntax error I think you can resolve it ;)